# Rails views stored in db and rendered properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I'm creating a simple CMS where there is a Page model that has a content field that stores the HAML code to be rendered for a page.  So I know how to store the HAML and then render it, but I'd also like to be able to use Rails helpers interspersed in the HAML and have that render properly.

So an example HAML file:

```
%p
  Come on over to 3rd Ward! Take a tour with one of our associates this summer and get a
  %strong FREE $25 Class Gift Card and ONE FREE DAY of COWORKING.
%h2 How awesome is that?
=render("shared/schedule_tour")
```

I can render the HAML:

```
template = Haml::Engine.new(Page.find(params[:id]).content)
template.render
```

But how do I get it to accept my Rails Helpers?